# Xdebug & PHPStorm & CakePHP - Cannot access protected property

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been trying to configure xdebug with PHPStorm for debugging CakePHP application.

I have been using this method - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

However when I start to debug Cake dies with a fatal error -
**Cannot access protected property Cake\Event\EventManager::$_listeners**

Also I get this error at the top of the screen, the error is 
**Notice (8): Undefined index: _loaded [CORE/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php, line 319]**

Code for the same is - >

```
311:     /**
312:      * Debug friendly object properties.
313:      *
314:      * @return array
315:      */
316:     public function __debugInfo()
317:     {
318:         $properties = get_object_vars($this);
319:         $properties['_loaded'] = array_keys($properties['_loaded']);
320:         return $properties;
321:     }
```

Also once this happens I have to restart apache every time after this happens or I get a connection reset -**ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Also, in my PHPStorm, I see this - Frame is not available.

I have spent an entire day on this and I cannot take it anymore!
I have another box on which the breakpoint works.

Comment: any luck resolving it ?

Comment: [This Github Issue](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos/issues/164) reports that it's an internal CakePHP issue, that's still around 3 years later.